# Get value of an selected input conrol from dynamically generated <tr> of a table in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having problem with a piece of code in jQuery. Here I am using the following code to dynamically generate rows for a table. Each row contains two input elements in two different TD. Here is the code used for it [Working Fine] :

```
$("#pr_row:last").before(
'<tr id="pr_row" class="prw"><td id="pno">'+k+'</td>
<td id="prod">'+tp[0]+'</td><td>'+tp[4]+'</td>
<td>'+tp[2]+'</td><td><input type="text" class="rate" id="rate" onchange="update()"  name="rate" value="0.00"> </td> 
<td> <input type="text" id="quan"  class="quan" onchange="update()"  name="quan" value="0.00"> </td> <td id="amt"> 0.00 </td> 
</tr>');
```

This code generated following table rows :

```
<tr id="pr_row">
<td id="pno">1</td>
<td class="undefined" id="prod">prod 1</td>
<td class="undefined">50</td>
<td>150</td>
<td><input class="rate" id="rate" onchange="update()" name="rate" value="0.00" type="text"> </td>
<td> <input id="quan" class="quan" onchange="update()" name="quan" value="0.00" type="text"> </td>
<td id="amt"> 0.00 </td>
</tr>
```

Now the problem is with the input elements in the rows. They invoke the following function, which needs to calculate the amount = rate * quan. Here is the code of function update() :

```
function update() {
    var row = $(this).parents('#pr_row');
    var price = Number(row.find('#quan').text()) * row.find('#rate').val();
    isNaN(price) ? row.find('#amt').html("N/A") : row.find('#amt').html(price);
    }
```

Upon successfully execution it should update the inner HTML of . But it is not working. Upon debugging I found that the function is unable to read the input values from "#quan" and "#rate". Please help me.

Comment: In the code which you say is generated, there is no `#pr_row` element.

Comment: You can't have strings span more than one line in JS unless you escape them at the end using a `\`, or split up each line and concat using `+`

Comment: Also - `$("#pr_row:last")` implies you have multiple `#pr_row`s, which you shouldn't do, as you IDs should be unique.

Comment: @IanClark the code was originally on 1 line, OP edited it to make it more readable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeh I thought so... fiddles are great...

Comment: @user2685384 - You shouldn't edit your answer to communicate with users, If you're trying to use someone's solutions, add a comment to it.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of errors you're making, and I'll address those later. For now, perhaps consider refactoring your code to look something like (**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ32J/4/)**):

```
// A standard input you keep duplicating
var $input = $('<input type="text" value="0.00" />')
$input.on("change", function() {
    var row = $(this).parents('.prw');
    var price = Number(row.find('.quan').val()) * Number(row.find('.rate').val());
    isNaN(price) ? row.find('.amt').html("N/A") : row.find('.amt').html(price);
});
// A method to copy our standard input into a new cell and assign it a name and class
function new_input_cell(name) {
    return $("<td></td>")
        .append(
            $input.clone(true)
                .attr({
                    'class': name,
                    'name' : name
                })
        );
}

$tr = $("<tr class='prw'></tr>");
$tr.append('<td class="pno">K VALUE</td><td class="prod">TP0 VALUE</td>',
           new_input_cell("rate"),
           new_input_cell("quan"),
           '<td class="amt"> 0.00 </td>'
          );
$(".prw:last").before($tr);
```

### Issues I've addressed:

- You're routinely using `ID`s where you should be using `class`es. `ID`s should be used to reference unique elements
- I don't think it's very good practice to use an `onclick` method anymore. Try assigning your events from within your script
- You were finding the `.text()` of your 'quan' element, not it's `.val()`.
- You were trying to convert your 'quan `.text()` to a number and then multiply it with the 'rate' `.val()`. Instead, you should convert the `.val()`s to numbers **and then** multiply them.
- Your long line of creating a jQuery object and DOM elements was very difficult to read, I've split that up into something which should be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Actually he converted the left argument to a number, then multiplied (which did in implicit conversion of the second string), but all the other issues are valid.

Comment: @HiTechMagic good spot, though there was no guarantee `.val()` is a Number so he needs to address that too.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you need to pass `this` into your update function when calling it via the onchange attribute.

Also, `Number(row.find('#quan').text())` should be `Number(row.find('#quan').val())` as it is an input so you want the value, not the text.

You should also not use ID's to identify multiple elements. Use a class instead.

Finally, the input tags should be closed properly as shown in the below HTML.

This code should work as you want:

JS

```
$(".pr_row:last").before('<tr class="prw pr_row"><td id="pno">'+k+'</td><td id="prod">'+tp[0]+'</td><td>'+tp[4]+'</td><td>'+tp[2]+'</td><td><input type="text" class="rate" onchange="update(this)" name="rate" value="0.00"/> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="quan" onchange="update(this)"  name="quan" value="0.00"/> </td> <td class="amt"> 0.00 </td> </tr>');

function update(element) {
    var row = $(element).parents('.pr_row');
    var price = Number(row.find('.quan').val()) * row.find('.rate').val();
    isNaN(price) ? row.find('.amt').html("N/A") : row.find('.amt').html(price);
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr class='pr_row'>
        <td id="pno">1</td>
        <td class="undefined">prod 1</td>
        <td class="undefined">50</td>
        <td>150</td>
            <td><input class="rate" onchange="update(this)" name="rate" value="0.00" type="text"/> </td>
            <td> <input class="quan" onchange="update(this)" name="quan" value="0.00" type="text"/> </td>
        <td class="amt"> 0.00 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Working Example - http://jsfiddle.net/TwkV2/

Comment: Hello @richard, <br/> used your solution [Appended to the main question] and now even the rows are not inserting.

Comment: Do you have an existing row with the class of `pr_row`? Any error messages displayed in the console?

Comment: @user2685384 please **read the comments** on all of our answers. You'll need to change your markup as it's wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML shown is not strictly correct. You are missing self-closing markers on the inputs. You are generating multiple duplicate id, which is also not valid. Suggest you use classes instead. You are also not passing this to the call (as in `onchange="update(this)"`). You also referenced `text()` instead of `val()` for the input values:

### Working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2CYxQ/1/

```
function update(ctrl) {
    var $c = $(ctrl);
    var $row = $(ctrl).closest('tr');
    var price = Number($row.find('.quan').val()) * $row.find('#rate').val();
    isNaN(price) ? $row.find('.amt').html("N/A") : $row.find('#amt').html(price);
}
```